# find element by attribute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` and i insert a `data-test` attribute in it :

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-test="test"></div>
</div>
```

Now i want to find inner div , with this expression :

```
alert($("#container").find("[data-test=test]").length);
```

But this is not working . Whats the problem here?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Tx5fX/).

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/CLtU2/ What jQuery version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try quoting your value:

```
alert($("#container").find('[data-test="test"]').length);
```

Comment: perfect answer, quotes was the problem. Thanks!!